# OMS agent can't heartbeat to Azure Monitor

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, azure

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 setup in a POC environment and i've installed the Azure OMS agent on the device but it keeps getting socket bind exceptions and it can't connect to the Azure Monitor service.

I followed the steps here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/6cc360a4-7835-4861-b122-82a43479ccf5/microsoft-monitoring-agent-is-unable-to-connect-to-loganalytics-workspace-event-id-4008?forum=opinsights

But I don't have any firewalls setup in this environment so I am not sure where the traffic is being blocked.

Here is the specific error message:

```
temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2019-02-07 02:41:03 +0000 error_class="RuntimeError" 
error="Net::HTTP.Post raises exception: SocketError, 
'Failed to open TCP connection to redacted.ods.opinsights.azure.com:443 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)'"
```

Here's what I checked:

- Port is open on the machine directly
- Port is allowed through the VNET (allowed 443 outbound to Azure Monitor)
- No external firewall on this subnet

So I am not sure wherelse the traffic may be getting block if the port is allowed through local firewall and the subnet, and there is no firewall. Am I overlooking something else?

Edit:
Yes I redacted the hostname.  I haven't specified a host name or endpoint for the monitoring agent. As far as i'm aware you don't have to. It's working on another identical box. I followed Azure's procedure to install on Linux and started the service up: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/oms-linux

I can ping google and otherwise access the internet.

Comment: (1) When you say “`redacted.ods.opinsights.azure.com`”, do you *mean* “`redacted.ods.opinsights.azure.com`”, or do you mean that you’re keeping your host name secret?  (2) It says “getaddrinfo: Name or service not known”.  That doesn’t mean that your traffic is being blocked; it means that you’ve specified an incorrect / invalid name.  What have you done to verify that your name(s) are valid?  E.g., can you ping it/them? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the agent using the same config and it's working now. Here are the instructions I followed

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4131455/how-to-reinstall-operations-management-suite-oms-agent-for-linux